# Displacement on subdivided mesh

Tags: three.js, webgl

I am trying to figure out how to get a detailed zbrush model to display with three.js, while keeping file size under or around 1MB.

Are we able to use a displacement+normal map on a subdivided mesh? I wasn't able to find this info in all my searches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, here are a couple of examples –

The moon demo:
http://whiteflashwhitehit.com/2011/02/21/a-moon-in-webgl/

The ninja head demo:
http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_normalmap.html